# Noun for something that reverse engineers something else?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a web application that can reverse engineer something. I'm thinking of describing it as a "reverse engineerer" but engineerer is, to my knowledge, not a word. What word/phrase could I replace "reverse engineerer" with?

Example:

"MyApp, an [xyz] reverse engineerer."

Comment: I would call it a "reverse engineer".

Comment: I’d call it a “reverse engineering tool”

Comment: If I saw the term ‘‘***a*** reverse engineer’’, I would think it was a reference to (1) a guy who was driving a train backwards, (2) an engineer who wears baseball caps with the visor pointing to the rear, or (3) somebody who was still trying to develop a perpetual-motion machine.     :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 2):

A **reverse-engineered piece of software**: something developed using reverse-engineering approach to another product.

A recent practical example: Hamrick Software company developed (legally, with a permission from authors) a 64-bit driver version for an older Epson scanner.

> *We reverse engineered the Epson Perfection 3200 driver and included it in VueScan so you can keep using your old scanner*.
>   https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/epson_perfection_3200.html

So according to their own words, they included a 'reverse-engineered Epson driver' in their scan software. In your example:

> *Application X is reverse-engineered Y*.

Answer (score 2):

Phillip K. Dick in his short story Paycheck illustrated your quandary of the vocation of a Reverse Engineer succinctly but never coined a unique term for it. As technology’s complexity makes this job description a profession I would venture to coin a new term that of ‘Revgineer’ I’m just spit-balling here but it may be time to step up and petition Encarta/Webster’s/Britannica etc. for acceptance of a ‘New” term.

Comment: Why not *revengeneer*?

Comment: @mahmudkoya that's a superb word you've created, but it sounds like somebody who engineers *revenge*.

Answer (score 0):

"Engineer" is a verb as well as a noun so calling your web app a "reverse engineer" sounds fine to me.

Reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engineer